# Read the file from datalake in databricks -No such file directory error

Tags: databricks, azure-data-lake, mount-point

I have a problem with reading the file from ADLS gen 2.

I have dont the mounting properly as after executing `dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/bronze')` I can see the file path.

the way how I did the mounting:

```
# dbutils.fs.mount(
#   source = "abfss://"+container_read+"@"+storage_account_name_read+".dfs.core.windows.net/",
#   mount_point = "/mnt/dataverse",
#   extra_configs = configs)
```

the way how I read the file:

```
with open('/mnt/dataverse/model.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    manifest = json.loads(data)
```

and it throws the error `No such file or directory`

Sketchy part is that I can read the file usign different cluster ( `runtime  11.3.x-scala2.12`) but after switching to `12.2` cluster I cant read it.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: are you able to read the file in 11.3 cluster using the same code? or different code? and did you tried with path like `/dbfs/mnt/mountpoint`?

Comment: yes, I am able to use it in another clsuter which is not using Unity catalog. but the one which has the problem (12.2) also supports the Unity catalog. I tried to decrease to11.3 runtime but still Im not able to read it. I also tried your code but still cant read it.

Comment: How you mounted the storage account, what are the configs here? using service principal?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I just tried to read the file in UAT env manually and tried mount the UAT data lake but got this error 
`py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore$Result com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.mount(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Map) is not whitelisted on class class com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore `  , not sure if I have to also mount in UAT or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the mount point `data` and got same error with your code.

[image]

Here, `with open()` not identifying the mount point might be reason for the reason. We need to give the `dbfs` path to this. To resolve the error, give the path like this.

```
/dbfs/mnt/<mount-point>/<filename>
```

To understand better about this path, Go to dbfs browser and click on file name in the mount point. You can see the File API format file path.

[image]

You can see that I am able to read the file, with the above file path.

[image]

If the issue still persists, it's better to raise a [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) on this.

Comment: I think your cluster is not supporting the Unity catalog. Thats why you are able to read it. I found a work around. Reading it using spark and then converting the df into dict. I will mark this answer as correct while you are on Hive_metastore it will work. As soon as the cluster supports UC it will not work.